# Is there a way to change the title bar color in the recent tab? I want it to display the accent color instead of the primary color

Tags: android

My icon blends in too much with the title bar color in the recents tab. Is there a way perhaps in the manifest or activity to change the color of that bar?

Comment: what is you application theme/activity theme ?

Comment: @ÅdəəlÅhmåd Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want to change the color of you "Toolbar". Try this :
In your **res>values>styles.xml** , add this code inside (already present) `<resource>` tags. Choose Hex code of color of your choice (here m using #FFFFFF for white )

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item> //ActionBar Color
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FFFFFF</item> //StatusBar Color
    </style>
```

Now in your **manifest.xml** , then do this to your activity tag :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".myActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/myTheme" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I'm using Toolbar instead of the built in actionbar so having a theme that includes the actionbar doesn't work.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and mark this as correct even though it's not exactly what I did but it got me thinking of the correct solution. Basically the primary color of your theme determines your actionbar color AND the bar that shows up as the title bar in the recents tab menu. If you are using the Toolbar API's just make sure to set the color of the toolbar explicitly and not from the system theme. This way you'll still have the correct status and toolbar colors along with the different recent tab title bar color.

Comment: This one works fine for me even for themes with ActionBars , `TabsLayout` API is deprecated and i never tried tabs adapter method myself, other team mate did that stuff